# Algebraic Varieties vs Smooth Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, smooth-manifolds

There are many posts I have read on that subject which seem unclear for me. My main question (it might be silly) is:

> "Every non-singular algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is a smooth
>   manifold."

(see: [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7439/algebraic-varieties-which-are-also-manifolds](http://topic%201))

How? For an algebraic variety we have the Zariski topology which is not even Hausdorff? How can they be diffeomorphic then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are absolutely right that a complex variety with its Zariski topology is not a complex manifold, nor even a Hausdorff topological space (unless it has dimension zero).
However there is a completely canonical way of associating to a complex  algebraic variety $X$ a complex analytic variety $X^{an}$.
More precisely that association  **Algvar $\to$ Anvar** is a functor.
This functor has been studied in detail by Serre in a ground-breaking [article published in 1956](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1956__6_/AIF_1956__6__1_0/AIF_1956__6__1_0.pdf) and universally known by its amusing acronym *GAGA*.
A typical result in the article (Proposition 6, page12)  is that $X$ is complete iff $X^{an}$ is compact: a highly non-trival result relying on a theorem of Chow.

In this set-up the result you are asking about can be stated as follows:
**An algebraic complex variety $X$ is regular (=smooth) if and only if the associated analytic variety $X^{an}$ is a complex manifold.**

**Edit**
[Here](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~arnoldt/Serre-GAGA.dvi) is an English translation of *GAGA*.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly (I also used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry) The theorem I mentioned in the first post works at most for projective algebraic varieties, and there is no theorem of the form:
"Regular (with no singular points) abstract algebraic variety (not necessary projective one !) can be canonically maid into a smooth variety" ?

Comment: I don't know about your first post, but the result  in bold at the end of my answer **An algebraic complex variety...** does not require projectivity and is valid for completely general complex algebraic varieties. So  I don't know why you write  " there is no theorem of the form: Regular (with no singular points) abstract algebraic variety..." because there **is** such a theorem.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I didn't understood the theorem you mentioned during firs reading, but it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, dear J.E.M.S.

Answer (score 3):

The statements it that if the variety is endowed with the relative topology as a subset of $\Bbb C^n$ then it is a manifold.

Comment: Two questions than: 
1. So that variety must be assumed to be subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^n$, can't be any algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ ?
2. (more important) What is so amazing about that, it seem trivial in the form restricted to subvarieties of $\mathbb{C}^n$ since nondegeneracy is just requiring that jacobian of submersion by polynomials is of max rank. I can as well say that every set is a smooth manifold.

Comment: No, you can't. A subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a subvariety or it is not, it does not depend on anything but the embedding in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and quite obviously not all subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are subvarieties... On the other hand, there is absolutely *nothing* amazing about the fact that smooth algebraic varieties are smooth manifolds, it's just completely trivial if you know what the words mean.

Comment: @CaptainLama but we are not asking wheather it is a $submanifold$